# Proving that if $Re(a_n)\to a$ and $Im(a_n)\to b$, then $a_n\to a+bi$

Tags: sequences-and-series, proof-verification

Let $a_n$ be a sequence of complex numbers.

Suppose $\Re(a_n)\to a\quad\text{and}\quad \Im(a_n)\to b$. Then,

$$\forall\epsilon >0,\exists N_{a}\in\mathbb{N}:n\geq N_a\implies |\Re(a_n)-a|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

$$\forall \epsilon>0\exists N_b\in\mathbb{N}:n\geq N_b\implies |\Im(a_n)-b|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}$$

Let $N=max(N_a,N_b)$, then by using the triangle inequality:

$$|\Re(a_n)-a|+|\Im(a_n)-b|\leq |\Re(a_n)+\Im(a_n)-(a+b)|<\frac{\epsilon}{2}+\frac{\epsilon}{2}=\epsilon$$

Is this correct? The given answer was different, and it instead used the inequality $$\text{max}(|x|,|y|)\leq |z|\leq \sqrt{2}\text{max}(|x|,|y|)\quad\text{for $z\in\mathbb{C}$}$$

Comment: Either inequality works.

Comment: For $a_n\to a+bi$ you need $|a_n-(a+bi)|\to 0$ so you really need an inequality that uses complex $$|a_n-(a+bi)|=\sqrt{(Re(a_n)-a)^2+(Im(a_n)-b)^2}$$ You can show easily enough, though, that $|z|\leq |x|+|y|$, so your bound is "good enough."